# How can I add users to the inMemoryAuthentication builder after it has been built?

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot

I have managed to load all the users into the AuthenticationManagerBuilder during the initial load of the application, but I have a requirement to add users post-startup.

Startup:

```
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

...

auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser(email).password(password).roles(roles.toArray(new String[roles.size()])).and().passwordEncoder(encoder());
```

This works great for a point in time, but I have a use case where users can be added while the application is running.

By which method can I do this post-startup (via controller/service)?  I'm thinking it might be the `InMemoryUserDetailsManager` (it contains the `createUser()` method) but I'm not sure how to reference or configure it.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The following code will do what you are asking:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        //whatever here
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(inMemoryUserDetailsManager());
    }

    @Bean
    public InMemoryUserDetailsManager inMemoryUserDetailsManager() {
        final Properties users = new Properties();
        users.put("user","pass,ROLE_USER,enabled"); //add whatever other user you need
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(users);
    }

}
```

Using the `InMemoryUserDetailsManager` you configured above a super simple controller that just adds and checks for the existence of a user would look like:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("user")
public class SimpleSecurityController {

    private final InMemoryUserDetailsManager inMemoryUserDetailsManager;

    @Autowired
    public SimpleSecurityController(InMemoryUserDetailsManager inMemoryUserDetailsManager) {
       this.inMemoryUserDetailsManager = inMemoryUserDetailsManager;
    }

    @RequestMapping("exists/{username}")
    public boolean userExists(@PathVariable("username") String username ) {
        return inMemoryUserDetailsManager.userExists(username);
    }

    @RequestMapping("add/{username}/{password}")
    public String add(@PathVariable("username") String username, @PathVariable("password") String password) {
        inMemoryUserDetailsManager.createUser(new User(username, password, new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>()));
        return "added";
    }
}
```

Also note that if you are using Spring Boot's autoconfiguration you will need to add

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = SecurityAutoConfiguration.class)
```

to prevent Spring Boot from trying to autoconfigure security

**Update**
As noted by @AdamMichalik, `@EnableWebMvcSecurity` is deprecated and should be replaced by `@EnableWebSecurity`

Answer (score 3):

I changed this code:

```
inMemoryUserDetailsManager.createUser(new User(username, password, new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>()));
```

from @geoend´s answer to:

```
inMemoryUserDetailsManager.createUser(User.withUsername(username).password(password).roles("USER").build());
```

because by default, a new user doesn't have any permissions.