# How to use InMemoryUserDetailsManager post autoconfiguration?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

In my Spring Boot based app - for the sake of simplicity - I rely on the Spring Web Security auto-configuration of the `InMemoryUserDetailsManager` via the `UserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration`.

For this purpose I've just set up a single user via properties(.yml) as follow:

```
spring.security.user:
  name: whatever
  password: xxx
  roles: USER
```

I'd just like to subsequently add extra users I might read from another source (properties or so - exact values not known at compile time), by calling the appropriate method on `InMemoryUserDetailsManager` i.e. `createUser(UserDetails user)` (inherited from interface `UserDetailsManager`). Basically in a `@Configuration`-like bean of mine:

```
@Autowired // Spring will inject its newly created InMemoryUserDetailsManager
private UserDetailsManager userDetailsManager;

// Maybe some annotation like @PostConstruct maybe? but should be conditioned to the existence of the above UserDetailsManager - can I do this?
public void loadMyUsers() {
    ...
    Collection<UserDetails> users; // my list of "users"/UserDetails
    users.stream().forEach(userDetailsManager::createUser);
}
```

I've seen this question: [How can I add users to the inMemoryAuthentication builder after it has been built?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25869260/how-can-i-add-users-to-the-inmemoryauthentication-builder-after-it-has-been-buil) but unfortunately answers lead to other directions that I'm expecting i.e. either by providing a REST endpoint to add users (1st answer), or by "hardcoding" the add of users (2nd answer).

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`ApplicationRunner` or `CommandLineRunner`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-command-line-runner) to execute some codes once Spring Boot has started and create users in these runner.

Code wise , It looks like:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication {

    @Autowired 
    private UserDetailsManager userDetailsManager;

    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner commandLineRunner(ApplicationContext ctx) {
        return args -> {
            User user=new User("Foo", "password", ......);
            userDetailsManager.createUser(user);
        };
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DangerApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: OK, but how will this "Runner" be executed?

Comment: It 's run method will execute right after the spring boot application bootstrap. I use lambda to represent the run method in this example