# Spring Security: all endpoints return status 200 and unresponsive to constraints as antMatchers

Tags: java, spring-security

I want to restrict usage of `endpoints` based on roles: `admin`/`user`.

So I'm trying to implement `Spring Security` using `NoOpPasswordEncoder` (for testing purpose),
but the **problem** is:
all endpoints return status `200` and unresponsive to constraints as `antMatchers`.

**To clarify:** I want to log in as `user` and get the error because of `antMatcher`:

```
.antMatchers("/api/addresses")
.hasAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN")
```

but I'm getting `200` using current configuration now.

I've tested `Spring Security` configuration in format:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(inMemoryUserDetailsManager());
    }

    @Bean
    public InMemoryUserDetailsManager inMemoryUserDetailsManager() {
        final Properties users = new Properties();
        users.put("admin","{noop}admin,ROLE_ADMIN,enabled");
        users.put("user","{noop}user,ROLE_USER,enabled");
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(users);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/addresses")
                .access("hasAuthority('ROLE_ADMIN')")
                .antMatchers("/api/address/**")
                .access("hasAuthority('ROLE_ADMIN') or hasAuthority('ROLE_USER')")
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }
}
```

based on [example config](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25871053/8370915).

While investigating, I've tried to comment, e.g. lines:

```
.antMatchers("/api/address/**")
.access("hasAuthority('ROLE_ADMIN') or hasAuthority('ROLE_USER')")
```

to check what happens and still receive `200`  when log in as user.

also I've tried to use `hasAuthority()` methods like:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(inMemoryUserDetailsManager());
    }

    @Bean
    public InMemoryUserDetailsManager inMemoryUserDetailsManager() {
        final Properties users = new Properties();
        users.put("ADMIN","{noop}admin,ROLE_ADMIN,enabled");
        users.put("USER","{noop}user,ROLE_USER,enabled");
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(users);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/addresses")
                .hasAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/api/address/**")
                .hasAnyAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN", "ROLE_USER")
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }
}
```

following the [correct order](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30819556/8370915) with `antMatchers()`, when more specific rules have to go first, but it still doesn't help me.

Does anyone know what I'm missing here? Thanks in advance for any ideas.

**UPD #1:**

I've tried to [clear cookies](https://askinglot.com/how-do-i-delete-cookies-from-my-postman) in Postman, log in as user, but I'm still getting `200`.

[image]

I'm getting `401` only if I don't use `Basic Auth` in Postman for `GET` request:

[image]

**UPD #2:**

I've reproduced this issue using versions of technologies:

- `Java 11`
- `spring-boot-starter-parent 2.5.3`
- `spring-boot-starter-security 2.5.3`

Comment: I tried the provided configuration in a sample application and it works as expected, i.e request to /api/addresses returns 401. A couple of things to check: 1) Where are you making the request from? Is there any chance the credentials are cached? 2) Do you have any other security configuration?

Comment: @EleftheriaStein-Kousathana, thank you for the answer. I'm testing on `Swagger` and `Postman`. Are both configurations working for you? Could you elaborate, please, where did you test it?

Comment: I used `curl localhost:8080/api/addresses`. If you are using Postman make sure you clear all cookies before making the request.

Comment: @EleftheriaStein-Kousathana did you get `401` after log in as `user` or just did request and without log in? I'm still getting `200` after log in as user - this is the problem. Also I [cleared all cookies](https://askinglot.com/how-do-i-delete-cookies-from-my-postman), as you mentioned and it didn't help me.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I get back a 403 response when requesting `curl -u user:user localhost:8080/api/addresses`. Is this the behaviour you are expecting? It would be beneficial to update the question with the behaviour that you are expecting, as it is not clear at the moment.

Comment: @EleftheriaStein-Kousathana, I've updated question with clarification and new screenshots, please, check.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I still get back a 403 response from `curl -u user:user localhost:8080/api/addresses` and from Postman. Try making the request from the command line and see if you get a 403. If that doesn't work, try creating a fresh project and adding your configurations one-by-one to see which one breaks the functionality. Everything in `SecurityConfiguration` looks good to me.

Comment: you are most likely getting 403s because of CORS. In the future, please enable DEBUG logs for spring security (use google) and the logs will tell you exactly why you are getting the various status codes.

Comment: @Toerktumlare, thanks for advice, I'll take this moment into account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **Cause & solutions:**

---

**The cause** of issue was *redundant* configuration [option](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-context-path#settingTheProperty):

`server.servlet.context-path=/api`

because `/api` prefix  was already present in `.antMatchers()`

---

**Solution #1:**

To fix it I've removed it from `application.properties` file and add this prefix directly to endpoints.

---

**Solution #2:**
It can be solved vice versa: remove prefix `/api` in `antMatchers()` and leave:

`server.servlet.context-path=/api`

using `application.properties`

---

**Solution #3:**

Also I've solved the problem using another configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(inMemoryUserDetailsManager());
    }

    @Bean
    public InMemoryUserDetailsManager inMemoryUserDetailsManager() {
        final Properties users = new Properties();
        users.put("admin","{noop}admin,ROLE_ADMIN,enabled");
        users.put("user","{noop}user,ROLE_USER,enabled");
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(users);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .httpBasic()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }
}
```

with adding [annotations](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-method-security#3-using-preauthorize-and-postauthorize-annotations) on methods of controller:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ROLE_ADMIN')")
```

and accordingly:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ROLE_ADMIN') or hasAuthority('ROLE_USER')")
```

---

As result I'm getting `403` instead of `200`:

[image]

Comment: You're welcome! Glad it was useful for someone as working use-case.